# How to get (and ignore) a value from Go channel

Tags: go, channel

I have the following code in a `select` statement. `finish` is of type `bool`. Actually, I don't even care of the value as long as I just receive anything. However, Go gives me an unused variable error. How can I get around it?

```
case finish := <- termSig:
```

My current workaround is to `Println(finish)`.

I had tried:-

```
case _ := <- termSig:
```

but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I wonder the downvote.

Comment: You can't declare `_`, though unnecessary, the second would have compiled with `case _ = <-termSig`

Comment: @AsadIqbal I downvoted because "This question does not show any research effort." As I pointed out in my answer, the official tutorial shows exactly this use case in the first page that mentions `select`, so it's nearly impossible not to come across on your own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just omit the variable and the `:=`:

```
case <-termSig:
```

Answer (score 2):

As is shown in the [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5) when `select` is introduced, you can have a case that doesn't initialize a new variable.

```
func fibonacci(c, quit chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    for {
        select {
        case c <- x:
            x, y = y, x+y
        case <-quit:  // looks like exactly your use case
            fmt.Println("quit")
            return
        }
    }
}
```